# Acer AN515-57: How to keep keyboard backlight on

Tags: 22.04, acer, keyboard-backlight

friends.

I have a laptop Acer model Nitro AN515-57 with BIOS 1.19. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.2.

My keyboard backlight turns off after 30 seconds.
I want to avoid this situation.

My BIOS hasn't the option "Keyboard Backlight Sleep" or the option "Keyboard Backlight Timeout".

The command **ls -l /sys/class/leds/** returns only:

```
input4::capslock ->../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock
input4::numlock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock
input4::scrolllock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock
phy0-led -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/leds/phy0-led
```

Any ideas of how can I keep the keyboard backlight turned on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** From the quick search over on the Acer community board, I found what appears to be the answer to your issue: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/538821/acer-nitro-5-keyboard-backlight. Short answer: the 30 second timeout is an Acer laptop "feature" when running on battery.